# Gesture recognizer on button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition

I'd like to implement a gesture recognizer (swipe action) for a button. The problem is, the buttons are create programmatically and are or aren't existent based on a few conditions. So, I don't know if there are buttons, or how many.

I know I need something like:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if (touch.view == aButtonView) {
        //get the button's tag
    }
}
```

Of course, the if-statement should return Yes when any button view is pressed...

Anyone has any idea on what the word `aButtonView` should be? Or if it's even possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should think about using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` instances. Attach the gesture recognizer to the button objects  -

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                            action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[button addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
[swipe release];
```

and in `handleSwipe:`

```
- (void) handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {
    NSInteger tag = swipe.view.tag;
}
```

---

it should be `if ( [gestureRecognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] ) {`

Comment: Wow dayum, this is why I love SO

Comment: @Deepak: Hmmm, though it looked good at first, it doesn't seem to work. It never returns YES on the statement you described, even though the button's action executes after releasing the button (touch up). Any idea?

Comment: What are you attaching the gesture recognizer to?

Comment: I've got a view controller, containing a table view. In the table view's cells are the buttons. I need to recognize the swipe on that button. The button's are added in the same class (the viewcontroller, tableview's delegate) as the gesturerecognizer is located. So I've got the gesturerecognizer added to the viewcontroller. Correct?

Comment: Does the swipe have a particular direction?

Comment: Not yet. I logged the outcome of the if-statement. Inside the if, i log YES. Outside of it, I log NO. Each time i swipe, doesn't matter where, it returns NO :(

Comment: Updated answer with an alternate suggestion.

Comment: Heya, I found out i used UIGestureRecognizer instead of the Swipe one. However, after updating that, it still didn't work. After that, I tried your renewed suggestion and added the line `NSLog(@"Swiped!");` to handleSwipe, with no succes :(

Comment: Wow cancel my last comment, I totally missed the part where I should swipe Upwards instead or Right. Imma go and get myself some coffee now. You're a hero!